# Can you detect a swipe up on android heads up notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, swipe, gesture

When a user swipes left and right on a heads-up notification, I know that you are able to `setDeleteIntent` to capture this gesture and write a custom intent to be fired.

But is it possible to detect when a user swipes up on a heads-up notification when the user snoozes it because at this point they are not dismissing it so the delete Intent never gets fired?

*I would like to know if users swipe the notification up vs left or right.*

Answer (score 0):

if you start to detect [common gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector),could it work out for you ? The same could be followed for notifications I believe.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

switch(action) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                "of current screen element");
        return true;
    default :
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
}
```